# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis authentication using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I'm planning to write an application using spring boot where you can create users from that application. I'm wondering whether there's a possibility of updating the user list of Apache ActiveMQ Artemis broker with the credentials of the user created by the spring boot application? I couldn't find any reference on internet addressing this issue

Answer (score 0):

The default security configuration for Apache ActiveMQ Artemis users properties files for user and role information. Either of these files can be updated at runtime and the broker will pick up those changes.